# Cannot receive messages to subscribed topic on mqtt paho

Tags: java, protocols, raspberry-pi, mqtt

Im running mqtt paho server on a win 7 laptop and the client on a raspberry pi which are connected with each other with a man cable.
Both the devices can ping each other.
When I run the client and server the client is getting connected to the server successfully subscribes to the topic but however the data that is published on the topic does not reach the RPI.
I have checked mosquito on the server ie  my laptop and mosquito receives The data published by the mqtt server.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Are these client subscribe on the same topic ? and also can you post some code like connection string mqtt.connect("topic" , port,timeout)

Comment: Yes I've cross checked they are publishing and subscribing to the same topic. The connection logic is mqtt.connect (topic, 192.168.2.1:1883) cannot give the topic cos of company confidentiality

Comment: Have you checked your firewall on winodws 7 desktop ?Make sure mqtt allow for connection on public and private network.

Comment: One more thing just disable your antivirus(if you have so , sometimes they are blocking the port 1883) and try to restart mosquitto borker.

Comment: Try using e.g. mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub to diagnose your problem outside of whatever code you are using.

Comment: Actually even if I run with the local host IP address or only local host i do not get the message even on the same computers as that of the server